# Strange class name issue in DataTables when using different functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am experiencing a strange issue with [DataTables](https://datatables.net/). In the docs sometimes it shows the class name with a capital D:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
```

Other times with a lowercase D:

```
var table = $('#example').dataTable();
```

Both work.. most of the time. My issue is two functions are conflicting. One needs the class to be lowercase and one needs uppercase.

For example, the [search function](https://datatables.net/reference/api/search%28%29#Example) needs uppercase (works):

https://jsfiddle.net/362cz1z7/

If I use lowercase (breaks):

https://jsfiddle.net/362cz1z7/1/

I also want to use the [fnSettings](http://fnSettings) function on the same table... And of course it needs lowercase so it breaks my search code.

Uppercase (breaks):

https://jsfiddle.net/362cz1z7/2/

Lowercase (works):

https://jsfiddle.net/362cz1z7/3/

Both give an error 'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function'. I am totally confused. If you look at their examples in the docs, some are uppercase and some are lowercase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments in the source code describe the situation better than I could (starting on line 14,670):

```
// With a capital `D` we return a DataTables API instance rather than a
// jQuery object
$.fn.DataTable = function ( opts ) {
    return $(this).dataTable( opts ).api();
};

// All properties that are available to $.fn.dataTable should also be
// available on $.fn.DataTable
$.each( DataTable, function ( prop, val ) {
    $.fn.DataTable[ prop ] = val;
} );
```

So I guess if you are trying to access the API directly, you use the capital D and if you are manipulating the object on the page, you use the lowercase d. Messy!

Comment: Wow so messy... I ended up using the following to get the settings... `$('#example').dataTable().fnSettings().aaSorting;` Thanks so much!